# Enable syntax highlighting in Qtcreator for the code in #ifdef

Tags: syntax-highlighting, qt-creator

I have been trying to enable syntax highlighting and see call hierarchy for code which is embedded in #ifdedfine block but I am not able to find the option for it. Could anyone please point me at how to do it? It works well for other code/files it's just the code in #ifdef block (e.g. #ifdef CPP_UNIT....#endif). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Code in `#ifdef` blocks IS syntax-highlighted IF THE CODE IS ACTIVE (e.g. if you have a `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN` and somewhere in your included headers `Q_OS_WIN` is defined, the code will be highlighted. Otherwise, it will be grayed-out.)

As a test, try temporarily replacing `#ifdef ...` with `#if 1`. If the latter works, then you know that `...` is undefined by that file or any included files.